# How does this call/cc expression work?

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, callcc

I am trying this on Racket and it gives out the answer as 5. But I cannot seem to figure out how it got to the answer.

```
((call/cc call/cc) (lambda (x) 5))
```

I expanded it as follows.

```
((call/cc (lambda (k) (call/cc (lambda (k1) (k k1))))) (lambda (x) 5))
```

Assuming the expansion is correct I still don't understand what happens when k continuation is applied to k1 continuation and how it does to the execution of outer lambda to yield 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(k k1)` would return `k1` as the return value of the outer `call/cc`. Then when you invoke `k1` (as part of `(... (lambda (x) 5))`), that returns 5 as the return value of the inner `call/cc`, which is then returned (as a normal return this time) as the return value of the outer `call/cc`.

Sorry, that was quite a mouthful. :-)

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding of the explanation. (k k1) returns with k1. Then (k1 (lambda (x) 5)) happens. Which returns with (lambda (x) 5). Then ((lambda (x) 5) (lambda (x) 5)) happens yielding 5. Did I get it correct?

Comment: Yep, that sounds reasonable.

Comment: Awesome. So in this case both k and k1 continuations are pretty much the same right?

Comment: They are not the same continuations (one returns to the outer `call/cc`'s caller, the other returns to the inner `call/cc`'s caller), but their effects are similar enough that you could consider it that way.